# Dynamic tooltip MVC3 razor

Tags: tooltip

I have text box which is not include long content so if it is lengthy content we should that content showing tootltip I need for MVC3  dynamic content tooltip. please explain it with example

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the easiest way is to just put the `@data_toggle = "tooltip"`, like this:

> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Matricula, new {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Matrícula",  @title = "Matrícula", @data_toggle = "tooltip", @data_placement = "bottom"})

Comment: Can you explain your code example? This will help your solution be understood, and perhaps win you points. Without an explanation no one will now why yours is the best.

Comment: Praticamente é só colocar a @data_toggle = "tooltip".